# Why does a "foot (止) kicking a person (人)" mean `here" (此)?

Tags: meaning

I am asking just about [meaning (2)](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E6%AD%A4) below. Meaning (2) flabbergasted me, because "here" is a bloodless,  unbiased, and uncommitted adverb. But "foot (止)) kicking a person (人)"  is forceful and violent, and may constitute criminal battery! How did "foot (止)) kicking a person (人)" compound to mean an adverb as mellow as 此?

> Origin unclear. Two possible explanations are (1) depicts a person ([人](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E4%BA%BA)) stopping ([止](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E6%AD%A2)), meaning "here", and (2) depicts a foot ([止](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E6%AD%A2)) kicking a person ([人](https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E4%BA%BA)), based on an earlier meaning "to kick" ([跐]>(https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E8%B7%90)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the referenced website is a good source for glyph origin and etymology. For glyph origin, the 《字源》 dictionary is much better start, while for etymology 《同源字典》 by 王力 is an authoritative guide which one cannot bypass.

First of all, the 造字本义 (original meaning upon character creation) of 此 is 以足踏人 (stamp on people). The emphasis is not on kicking, but on stamping. It evolved as follows: to stamp on people → to stamp on anyone/anything → to step on anything. So some theories hold it is from this meaning that the pronoun 此 is abstracted: stepping on the ground is a vivid body language to indicate "this".
[image]

Secondly, 跐 doesn't have the meaning to kick. It should be made clearer that 跐 is a 后起加旁分化字 (roughly means later-coined component-added derivative) of 此, which means 蹋, 蹈, 履 (step/stamp on sth.). 此 is the root glyph. But later when more and more derived meanings and phonetic loans are added to this glyph, people created other related glyphs to represent some meanings in order to reduce confusion. In this case, the meanings of 蹋, 蹈, 履 were assigned to 跐 and the pronoun meaning was kept to 此. This is very common in Chinese characters where the original glyph now represents a derived/loaned word while a derived glyph represents the original meaning. Later 跐 also acquired another meaning of 脚下滑动, which is now the most active meaning in dialects and the meaning of 蹋, 蹈, 履 is almost lost.

Thirdly, whether the pronoun meaning of 此 is a derived meaning or a phonetic loan is still not clear. A phonetic loan means that the glyph is borrowed to encode an unrelated word which has the same/similar sound to the glyph. From 《同源字典》, we see that 是、此、斯、兹 have the same origin, sound very similar and all means the same thing "this". This is not a conclusive evidence but yet a strong indicator that the pronoun meaning of "this" encoded by 此 is a phonetic loan. Also, pronouns in Chinese are phonetic loans in general. This is quite natural since the concepts are fundamental and were likely emerged at a very early stage but they are also highly abstract and difficult to encode with a pictogram, an ideogram, or an ideogrammic compound.

Comment: Thanks. You recommended《字源》and 《同源字典》 by 王力. Are these two listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_dictionaries?

Comment: @user Nope. I'm referring to https://book.douban.com/subject/25720782/ and https://book.douban.com/subject/3008543/. Physical books might be hard to get, but pdf's and mdict files are easily obtainable.